# Docker Build does not break on compiling .NetCore Projects with missing files - instead it says "successfull"

Tags: docker, .net-core, build

Is there a possibility to break the docker build process if there are sources which cannot be found?
My colleagues and I thought this would be like every other build process: Expected source is not found? -> Cancel the process.
But we found out, docker build ignores these errors and builds happily and succesful a container, which explode at runtime.

I found the reason why the build failed and repaired the Dockerfile (missing copy instruction), but this is not the question. The problem is: why can the build be successful if files are missing? And how to tell docker build to stop working if there are errors?

Build Log:

```
...

Skipping project "/SomeFolders/MyOtherProject/MyOtherProject.csproj" because it was not found.
Restore completed in 225.55 ms for /MyProject/MyProject.csproj.
Restore completed in 225.56 ms for
MyProject/MyProject -> /MyProject/MyProject/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/MyProject/MyProject.dll

...

Build succeeded.

... some more steps ...
Successfully built 6c96bf48a019, Step 27/27
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1.1-alpine AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
LABEL maintainer="ECKD KIGST GmbH"

COPY ["nuget.config", "./"]
COPY ["SomeFolders/", "./"] (this was missing in the first run)
COPY ["Nachricht/", "./Nachricht"]

WORKDIR MyProject

RUN dotnet restore "MyProject.csproj" 

RUN dotnet build "MyProject.csproj" -c Release --no-restore

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyProject.csproj" -c Release --no-restore --no-build -o /app/publish

...

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyProject.dll"]
```

Build.ps1

```
$scriptDir = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
& docker build -f $scriptDir/Dockerfile --build-arg http_proxy=$env:http_proxy --build-arg https_proxy=$env:https_proxy --build-arg no_proxy=$env:no_proxy -t my-project:latest $scriptDir/../../.
```

Has anyone a solution for that?
Reading the build log for "Skipping project" is not an option. Especially not in automated build and deployment pipelines...

We are happy and thankful for any help.

Comment: This seems unrelated to Docker.  Wouldn't you get the same behavior if you deleted the SomeFolders folder on your machine and tried to build your project outside the context of Docker?  It doesn't seem like you have any compile-time dependency on the content of the SomeFolders folder, so that would be the main reason why the build didn't fail.  The fact that dotnet build skips projects that don't exist is really your complaint here.  Seems like you should just log an issue at https://github.com/dotnet/sdk to have the option to fail on such a scenario.

Comment: Thank you Matt. Indeed it seems to be a problem of dotnet build. If I delete "SomeFolder" in my Filesystem, the same warning message appeared: ```C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1850,5): warning : The referenced project '..\..\SomeFolders\ProjectB\ProjectB.csproj' does not exist.```. The project is related as project reference. I take your advice and ast github.com/dotnet/sdk for this option.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/12934